# Trouble with apt-get install due to multiple linux-images?

Tags: apt, disk-image

So I was trying to install python-numpy, but I've been getting this error:

```
masonscott@amory:~/Workspace/research/nsf-cogneuro-feb11$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-generic-lts-wily thermald
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 423 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 202179 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic (4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.2.0-27-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.2.0-27-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
grep: /boot/config-4.2.0-27-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_W3v9Np/lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_W3v9Np/lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic (4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic (4.2.0-34.39~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.2.0-34-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic
grep: /boot/config-4.2.0-34-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_dC3KKx/lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_dC3KKx/lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic (4.2.0-34.39~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic
 linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic
 linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
masonscott@amory:~/Workspace/research/nsf-cogneuro-feb11$
```

So for some reason it seems I have the 27 & 34 images installed

and the output of

```
uname -r
```

is

```
4.2.0-30-generic
```

and all the stuff that is missing in the error message like /boot/System.map-4.2.0-... is correctly installed for 4.2.0-30, so I'm not sure what to do

After trying to remove the old disk image with

```
sudo dpkg --purge ...
```

I'm getting this error:

```
masonscott@amory:~$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic
(Reading database ... 202179 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic (4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic
```

What might the problem be with this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it looks as you have to many images  "MaxReports is reached"

You need to remove some kernels.

**Warning: Removing kernel packages can be dangerous, and might even leave your system unable to boot.**

Fist check what kernel you are using:

uname -r

**Do Not remove this kernel!**

List all kernels installed with:

```
dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)
```

Now remove the correct OLD kernels (keep a backup if possible)

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.2.0-15-generic
```

Where the image matches your old kernel

Then update & upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Next check you have the current kernel

```
sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade
```

**Alternative way:**

An alternative is Synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After installing and running the program- search:

```
linux-image
```

Right-click a kernel and choose complete removal and finally click the Apply button to delete the kernel.

Repeat the search but this time for linux-header - you can delete the associated headers for the kernel image chosen previously.

**Synaptic though will not attempt to verify what you are trying to remove... you could inadvertently delete your newest kernel - or even delete all of your kernels via this tool leaving you with an unbootable Ubuntu!.**